# (AssemblyScript + ReactJS) Can not sign transactions for account test.near on network shared-test

Tags: nearprotocol

When i run `yarn test`, i got this error:

> Can not sign transactions for account test.near on network shared-test, no matching key pair found in InMemorySigner(UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(D:\React Native\Near demo\NEARForum\neardev)).

```
  at Account.signTransaction (node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:86:19)
  at node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:111:34
  at Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)
  at Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:110:24)
  at Account.createAndDeployContract (node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:208:9)
  at LocalTestEnvironment.setup (node_modules/near-cli/test_environment.js:39:9)
```

someone tell me what i need to config for testing please. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Same problem here running test, did you solve it?